# Facebook API works, but not with codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk

I'm working on a site which uses the Facebook API to log users in, but I'm having some baffling trouble with the Facebook API itself.  I think it's a result of using CodeIgniter.

I added a PHP script that does not use Codeigniter, and it can connect.  It looks like this:

```
require_once("application/libraries/Facebook/facebook.php");

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => 'appid-removed-for-question',
        'secret' => 'secret-removed-for-question',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
echo $user;
```

This returns the appropriate UID from Facebook.

As soon as I try to do this using a CodeIgniter library, the UID consistently comes back as 0.  Here's the library code:

```
include(APPPATH.'libraries/Facebook/facebook.php');

class Fb_connect extends Facebook{

    public $user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->config->load("facebook",TRUE);
        $config = $CI->config->item('facebook');
        parent::__construct($config);

        $this->user = $this->getUser();
        echo $this->user;
    }
}
```

I've double and triple-checked my appid and secret in the config file, and even echoed it here to make sure it's coming through as an array correctly, but still nothing.  `$this->user;` constantly returns 0 for the UID.  What am I missing?

I just saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190668/facebook-apis-require-login-to-work-with-codeigniter) which talks about the uri_protocol being the problem, but I had to set `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';` to get my mod_rewrite script working in the first place, which makes me wonder if it's the same issue or not.  Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question I linked to actually fixed the problem for me:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 
    (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && 
     strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'apps.facebook.com') !== false) ? 
         "PATH_INFO" : "REQUEST_URI";
```

Answer (score 0):

use this.. 
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$this->config->item('app_folder_path')."application/libraries/Facebook/facebook.php");

Make sure you've set the app_folder_path config variable in your config.php file.

Comment: Yeah it actually wasn't having a problem loading the Facebook API - as my answer below stated, I had the change the uri_protocol to `PATH_INFO` if the referrer was facebook, or `REQUEST_URI` otherwise.

Thanks for the answer, in any case!